# I can't recreate the JSON object from unescaped Java string of JSON

Tags: java, json, apache, unicode-escapes

I am facing some issue in the following code.

```
  import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
 * 
 * @author ajmalsha
 *
 */
public class test {

    /**
     * 
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String value="[Mother’s Day, Birthday \"Add to Cart\"]";

        JSONObject data= new JSONObject();
        data.put("title", value);
        System.out.println(data);
        String finalData=org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(data.toString());
        System.out.println(finalData);
    }

}
```

The output of the above code is

```
{"title":"[Mother\u2019s Day, Birthday \"Add to Cart\"]"}
{"title":"[Mother’s Day, Birthday "Add to Cart"]"}
```

In the above first JSON were generated normally, In this the `’` of `Mother’s` were replaced with `\u2019`

I am able to retrieve the original value using `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils` but not able to reconstruct the JSON from this `finalData`  String.

Can any one please help.

Comment: If you unescape a string to what Java normally escapes then how do you expect a JSON parser to always be able to work with it?

Comment: In my input i have  Mother’s is changed to  Mother\u2019s. I need to avoid this changes thats why i do like this. Is there any other solutions available?

Comment: Since you are using `JSONObject` to create the json I'd use a parser of the same library to parse it again - not some Java-based utility.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need this process just serialize and deserialize as below.
If you try to read unescaped json from file and construct JSONObject it throws org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError. You should use escaped json to reconstruct it.

```
    String value="[Mother’s Day, Birthday \"Add to Cart\"]";

    JSONObject data= new JSONObject();
    data.put("title", value);
    System.out.println(data.toString());

    String deserialized = new JSONObject(data.toString()).getString("title");
    System.out.println(deserialized);
```

Output :

```
{"title":"[Mother\u2019s Day, Birthday \"Add to Cart\"]"}
[Mother’s Day, Birthday "Add to Cart"]
```

Comment: my expected output and your outputs are different. I need the out put in the same form of JSON but need to avoid the unicode conversion

Comment: I meaned to say that you can deserialize from data.toString() and if you want to show json with quotes you can use org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(data.toString());